# How to replace war in a EAR?

Tags: war, web-deployment, ear

I have a Ear file. It contains a war. I have another war for the same source. When I replaced the war in the Ear with my war and deployed in the server, it didn't work.
Basically the difference between these two wars are only 2 class files. These 2 classes are compiled against my war files.

Comment: Didn't work is horribly vague, and what did the server log?  What server?

Comment: It is Oracle application server, version 10.